# Python regular expression to capture phrases?

Tags: python, regex

I want to figure out a regex pattern capable of capturing the operation and the two registers or addresses it acts on for a given snippet of assembly code. This is what I have so far:

```
import re

assembly_code = """
    lea    r8, [rcx + 8*rax]
    movsd  xmm0, qword ptr [rcx + 8*rax]   ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    mov    rcx, r9
    xor    edi, edi
    .p2align    4, 0x90
LBB0_12:                                ##   Parent Loop BB0_2 Depth=1
                                        ##     Parent Loop BB0_3 Depth=2
                                        ##       Parent Loop BB0_4 Depth=3
                                        ##         Parent Loop BB0_10 Depth=4
                                        ##           Parent Loop BB0_11 Depth=5
                                        ## =>          This Inner Loop Header: Depth=6
    movsd  xmm1, qword ptr [r13 + 8*rdi]   ## xmm1 = mem[0],zero
    mulsd  xmm1, qword ptr [rcx]
    addsd  xmm0, xmm1
    movsd  qword ptr [r8], xmm0
    add    rcx, 2048
    lea    r12, [rsi + rdi]
    add    r12, 1
    add    rdi, 1
    cmp    r12, r14
    jl     LBB0_12
## %bb.13:                              ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_11 Depth=5
    add    rax, 1
    add    r9, 8
    cmp    rax, rbx
    jl     LBB0_11
"""

pattern = r"\b(mov|movaps|movups|movaps|movss|movsd|movlps|movhps|movlpd|movhpd|movd|movq)\b\s+(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+(\s*\[.*?\])?)"

matches = re.findall(pattern, assembly_code)
for match in matches:
    print("Instruction: ", match[0])
    print("Operand 1: ", match[1])
    print("Operand 2: ", match[2])
    print("---")
```

But the output looks as follows:

```
Instruction:  movsd
Operand 1:  xmm0
Operand 2:  qword
---
Instruction:  mov
Operand 1:  rcx
Operand 2:  r9
---
Instruction:  movsd
Operand 1:  xmm1
Operand 2:  qword
---
```

I am targeting patterns like `qword ptr [r13 + 8*rdi]` in its complete form. How to modify the pattern to make it capture the full string properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 3rd group I'd use something like `[^,#\n]+` which matches *one or more* of what is [[**^not** in class]](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). A [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<! )` can prevent to end in space or use [e.g. `[^,#\n]*[^\s,#]`](https://regex101.com/r/KjK3bl/2) alternatively.

```
\b(mov(?:aps|ups|aps|ss|sd|lps|hps|lpd|hpd|d|q)?) +(\w+) *, *([^,#\n]+(?<! ))
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KjK3bl/1) or the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##nZTRbtowFIbv8xRnQZMSMChO6BSiMaRqF6tUabvYHdDKxO6SKXFcx6xpxbsz24RCCtLKLIIT@z@fT47/WDyrrOLRdpuXopIKJHMcUtesXBXP92lFGUzBdV0HdCsYMZ2MEcxl2sAA4r4kzdJOltWfmgI0ZRkgeHyqJAWhZFeoZb2elWhqycp5sEQvTFZ7gKWnDQI5sUNNJU3HaI7Mnx0biZAU@S9u7scIgmYSOLfX18E9DhP4R9OLA/wgknEFt1UlwMSF8JUJlU2xA@9sFnMKilpQeCnoFDVuUdHlqFMYDlra@H9oZ3i45V1dwpt@OTz@zPIabjhnckf9xghlMmmxn974CXf9hKOdn2h@8BM@56d1cR6Qto4llB4ca2TH6x4HxEs7H@yjXm0aBuO482Xg0Hwada4zNPl1Aswc7owYW@9G0lK8aiTe7dPvwtaq9bajX/TjajXCUfKOrcu5LWzSVnZ6Ztv2SZDmbVoTBHEnKyORq@Y0K@yYo8ERRCkmud4D6S5Wnq6gN0uIqDdrfZm@1j@6KfRdpq9CUN3TDd08@jN/Dgu1HHiLp4EPfQR9b36Heguuh2afP4Dva35JVJqx2vDZ6CHnlBSF1y6KoHNa@c6DPjNsgClCG5nY1IXMufLcG14ruU5VXvEEXLTTaOf4x6LvgknCKeAjCT4vCY8kYVcyHA5df7v9Cw) - Use `[ \t]` instead of   where tabs can occur.

Further did some changes like shortening the pattern, use of `\w` *word character* in 2nd group, dropping *word boundary* in `\b\s+` where it looked redundant (`\s` already requires words to end).